# Math labels get doubled after converting PDF to SVG

Tags: fonts, pdf, pstricks, conversion, svg

I have a diagram written in PSTricks as follows.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm,12pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](6,6)
\pstTriangle[PointNameA=\alpha,PointNameB=\beta,PointNameC=\gamma](4,1){A}(1,3){B}(5,5){C}
\pstCircleABC{A}{B}{C}{O}
\rput[c](3,2.5){$\angle x y z = 30^\circ$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The PDF output as well as PNG outpus are just fine, as follows.

[image]

However, if I convert the PDF to SVG with the following command,

```
inkscape -z -f "test.pdf" -l "test.svg"
```

I got a strange output as follows.

[image]

There are several points I want to fix:

- the missing fonts
- the missing dots
- the missing math labels
- unnecessary "b" like symbols
- the math labels get doubled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conversion from dvi to svg with `dvisvgm` works fine, provided you load the relevant font packages:

```
    \documentclass[border=1cm,12pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}%
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb}
    \usepackage{pst-eucl}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](6,6)
    \pstTriangle[PointNameA=\alpha,PointNameB=\beta,PointNameC=\gamma](4,1){A}(1,3){B}(5,5){C}
    \pstCircleABC{A}{B}{C}{O}
    \rput[c](3,2.5){$\angle x y z = 30^\circ$}
    \end{pspicture}

    \end{document}
```

Screenshot of the resulting .svg file in Opera:

[image]

Comment: Opera has nothing to do with this, in my opinion. With my preamble, the font is `cm-super`. Is it installed?

Comment: If you have `lm`, use it. The point seems to have vector fonts.

Answer (score 2):

Use `xelatex` for the pdf:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm,12pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](6,6)
    \pstTriangle[PointNameA=\alpha,PointNameB=\beta,PointNameC=\gamma](4,1){A}(1,3){B}(5,5){C}
    \pstCircleABC{A}{B}{C}{O}
    \rput[c](3,2.5){$\angle x y z = 30^\circ$}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: no, the above dots are internally coded with a corresponding character. Don't know what inkscape does